# Software to automatically copy files when connected to the USB port of the computer

Tags: usb

Is there a software for Windows (Windows XP and above) that will do a background copy of the thumbdrive to a specific folder when the USB thumbdrive device is plug into the USB port of the computer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Secret USB Copier](http://steppschuh.net/software/usbcopier/)

The Secret USB Copier enables you to automatically copy files from connected USB drives to your hard drive. It detects plugged-in removable drives and scans their files without letting the owner know. You can set filters depending on which files you want to copy. It provides lots of customization possibilities, such as file size, extension, date and more. The tool can run completely invisible or imitate a fake USB Guard (Malware protection).

If you are running Windows XP, you may need to install the Micorsoft .Net Framework first.

[image]
[image]
[image]